# Distinct() does not work properly with time stamps in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

If I run following query I will have duplicates for `2021-03-28 04:00:00` . How can I avoid these duplicates?

```
SELECT distinct(ts) as date  FROM ( --(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') TO_CHAR(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00:00')
                SELECT '2020-10-21'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
                UNION
                SELECT '2021-03-29'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
                ) AS t TIMESERIES ts AS '1 Hour' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
```

Comment: `distinct` [is not a function](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/distinct/). It always applies to all columns of the SELECT list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any duplicates, otherwise this query would return some rows:

```
SELECT ts,count(*) as occ FROM (
  SELECT ts FROM (
   SELECT '2020-10-21'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
   UNION
   SELECT '2021-03-29'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
  ) AS t 
  TIMESERIES ts AS '1 Hour' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
) b
GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
-- out  ts | occ 
-- out ----+-----
-- out (0 rows)
```

What is different in your query?